# PHP: calculating birthday from age

Tags: php, mysql, comparison, date

Yes, this may sound strange.

In the advanced profile searching form, where you can filter by age.

Now you would type 18 or some other age in the field.

I am storing the birthdays, in the mysql db, in the birthday field in users i have example: 1990-02-02

How can i filter by age then, in a query?

Should i first make a query before, make all users birthdays to age, and then compare them? Would be too much, to take each one user.

Answer (score 2):

I bet this is what you are searching for:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, mytable.birthday,'$currentTime') > '$ageFromForm';
```

To sort the data you would perform this :

```
SELECT *, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, mytable.birthday, '$currentTime')) AS age 
FROM mytable WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'$birthday','$currentTime') > '$ageFromForm' 
ORDER BY age;
```

I hope this helps ;)
Slavic

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should work as a basis to start from:

```
SELECT <columns> FROM users WHERE birthday < SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 18 YEAR)
```