# Calculate age from datebirth sql field?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query I am using and it is in page 1 not inside the function.

```
<?php
$sql2= mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM catego WHERE category_id = '$idc'");
$categoryCount = mysql_num_rows($sql2); 
if ($categoryCount>0 )
{
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);     
    $id = $row2["category_id"];


    $birthdate = $row2["birthdate"];
    $address = $row2["address"];
}
?>
```

Comment: What language are you programming in? EDIT - PHP I see

Comment: Why is it formatted in that bizarre way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I easily determine the age from an birthday? (php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203651/how-do-i-easily-determine-the-age-from-an-birthday-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP calculate age](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845208/php-calculating-birthday-from-age

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533890/get-an-age-from-a-d-o-b-field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an age from a D.O.B field in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533890/how-to-get-an-age-from-a-d-o-b-field-in-mysql)

Comment: Get age from DoB in your SQL and then just use it in PHP. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533890/how-to-get-an-age-from-a-d-o-b-field-in-mysql/22504155#22504155

Comment: Use SQL like this    SELECT category_id, address, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE()) AS age
FROM catego WHERE category_id = NNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple php function could be something like the following:

```
function birth_date ($birth_date){
    list($y,$m,$d) = explode(",",$birth_date);
    $y_diff  = date("Y") - $y;
    $m_diff = date("m") - $m;
    $d_diff   = date("d") - $d;
    if ($m_diff < 0 || $d_diff < 0) { $y_diff--; }
    return $y_diff;
}
```

i.e split on your commas, work out the differences, adjust for which side of their birthdate the day/month is, if so reduce the year by one, then just return the year.

Then in your page you can put:

```
<li><span class="label">Age:</spa><?php$age = getage($birthdate); echo $age;?> </li>
```

**EDIT**:

```
<?php
function birth_date($birth_date){
    list($y,$m,$d) = explode(",",$birth_date);
    $y_diff  = date("Y") - $y;
    $m_diff = date("m") - $m;
    $d_diff   = date("d") - $d;
    if ($m_diff < 0 || $d_diff < 0) { $y_diff--; }
    return $y_diff;
}

$sql2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catego WHERE category_id = '$idc'");
$categoryCount = mysql_num_rows($sql2); 
if ($categoryCount>0 )
{
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);     
    $id = $row2["category_id"];
    $birthdate = $row2["birthdate"];
    $address = $row2["address"];

    $age = birth_date($birthdate);
}
?>
```

Comment: Peter how will the function know, which memeber is it picking up? Do I have to do a SELECT somewhere to specify the code which memeber is that we are refering?

Comment: How do I call this functino peter? I am calling it like <?php $age = getAge($row2['birthdate']);
echo $age; ?> and it throws an error Calling undefined function.

Comment: The function as I wrote it is called birth_date. So you would put:
$age = birth_date("2000,03,03"); echo $age; or your $row['birthdate'] equivalent.

Comment: ok let me see what is wrong it seems like I did that but let me check just in case, above I have edit the original post you can see it is similar to what you just said.

Comment: Also, in PHP unless in a class it should be "function myfunc(args){}" not "public function myfunc(args){}"

Comment: ALSO: you haven't added PHP tags: <li><span class="label">Age:</spa> <?php $age = getage($birthdate); echo $age; ?></li>

Comment: Or if using shorthand <?= getage($birthdate); ?>

Comment: ok Yes I am not in a class! cool let me get the public function out

Comment: I have updated my answer for you. I would be grateful if, after asking me for all this help on my solution, you actually marked it as the correct answer...

Comment: Though, for the record, doing it in SQL is nicer. If you post your query I can update my answer to show how it should be done.

Comment: hey I was off for a while I will try it now Sr.

Comment: it works peter, the only thing is that I put the function in a function.php file and call it in another file. the functions is require_once in the file 
include_once"scripts/functions.php"; but it didn't pull up the birth_date function, inside the query. But once I put the function inside the query within the scope of the query then it worked. thought I wanted to keep it nice and clean all apart

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT YEAR(SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL DATE_FORMAT("1975,09,02", "%Y-%m") YEAR_MONTH)) fs_age;
```

Comment: Isn't this SQL? They are using PHP

Comment: It is. He used the word "field", so I figured out that SQL is more appropriate. Besides, have a look at the subject.

Comment: This select is not picking any fields from the database? my field is birthdate

Comment: So replace the date in the example with your field.  ... DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, "%Y-%m") ...

Comment: Coling do I have to do a function for this one or just iterate it once

Comment: Use that SQL when querying the database - ie. SELECT first_name, last_name, other_field, YEAR(SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, "%Y-%m") YEAR_MONTH)) age FROM your_mysql_table;

Comment: But I don't know where to structure it Will I have a query in the same page where birthdate field is selected, I would like to use that query instead of westing it for this case. I was wondering if I can use a function instead and call it.

Comment: coling the query I have is above can you take a look

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, there are a few ways to do this.  Here are some good resources:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1310

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/19953-calculating-age-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Like this, in your language of choice:

```
function getAge(dateOfBirth)
{
DateTime now    = DateTime.Today;

int years   = now.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
// subtract another year if we're before the birth day in the current year

if (now.Month < dateOfBirth.Month || (now.Month == dateOfBirth.Month && now.Day < dateOfBirth.Day))
 --years;

    return years;
}
```

Comment: the argument dateOfBirth is coming from the call? how would you call it?